# jQuery AJAX with Multiple Array data Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've successfully posted a single array, but I can't figure out how to send more than one array in an AJAX post. Here is my code for one array:

```
var a = new Array();
// fill array
var a_post = {};
a_post['array1[]'] = a;

$.ajax({
    url: "submitOrder.php",
    data: a_post,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

And in submitOrder.php I have:

```
$array1= $_POST['array1'];

foreach ($array1 as $a => $b)
echo "$array1[$a] <br />";
```

This works fine. However, when I try to add a second array `b_post` to the `data:` field, it doesn't work. I tried `data: {a_post, b_post},` and a few variations of that, but I can't get it to work properly. While I'm at it, how would I then load `submitOrder.php` after posting rather than show an alert of the data?

**UPDATE**

Using Nicolas' suggestion, I got this to work changing the data field to:

```
data: {'array1':JSON.stringify(a), 'array2':JSON.stringify(b)},
```

However, I also need to add the rest of the form data that has been input by the user. I can get this data with `$(this).serialize()` but if I try to add that to the `data` field, it does not work. How can I add this data to the above line?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

What ended up working the way I originally had hoped for (with Nicolas' help):

```
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
var a_string = JSON.stringify(a);
formData.push({name: 'array1', value: a_string});
var b_string = JSON.stringify(b);
formData.push({name: 'array2', value: b_string});

$.ajax({
    url: "submitOrder.php",
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data should be encapsuled this way

```
data: {'first_array':JSON.stringify(array1),'second_array':JSON.stringify(array2)}
```

Then in PHP:

```
$array1 = json_decode($_POST['first_array']);
$array2 = json_decode($_POST['second_array']);
```

You can add the rest of the inputs as well.

```
data: {'first_array':JSON.stringify(array1),'second_array':JSON.stringify(array2),'input1':$(input[name="input1"]).val()}
```

Just repeat with all the inputs you want to send.

```
'input1':$(input[name="input1"]).val(),'input2':$(input[name="input2"]).val(),... etc
```

Comment: This is working nicely for my purposes, however I'd also like to include my standard form data as well. The easiest way to do this would be adding `$(this).serialize()` to the data field, but this is not allowed. How could I also include the rest of the input data from the form?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with the full solution that worked.

Comment: How we can decode this in Asp.net C# ? @Kevin_TA